# Graph Decomposition and graph factor

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph *G* is *H*-decomposable does it imply that *G* has *H*-factor?

Answer (score 2):

No.  An $H$-factor is a set of *vertex-disjoint* copies of $H$ that partition the vertex set of a graph, while an $H$-decomposition is a set of *edge-disjoint* copies of $H$ that partition the edge set of a graph.

For example, let $H = K_3$ and let $G$ be the $5$-vertex graph consisting of two triangles with a point in common.  Then $G$ clearly has an $H$-decomposition, but, since $3 \nmid 5$, it cannot have an $H$-factor.

Comment: Say i have a graph _G_ with _3m_ vertices, and that _G_ is $C_3$-decomposable. Can i say now that _G_ has $C_3_-factor?

Comment: @kim_kibun Again, not necessarily.  Let $G$ be the $6$-vertex graph obtained by taking a triangle and adding three vertices, each adjacent to two of the vertices of the triangle.  (More formally, let the vertices of the triangle be $u$, $v$, and $w$, and let the other three vertices be $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Let $a$ be adjacent to $u$ and $v$, $b$ to $v$ and $w$, and $c$ to $w$ and $u$.)  Then $G$ has a $K_3$-decomposition but no $K_3$-factor.